# Sum on a group not including one of the rows of the detail in a grouping

Tags: algorithm, reporting-services

I have my data set

```
column1  column2 column3 column4 column5

data1     data1    data1   data1  data1
data2     data2    data2   data2  data2
data3     data3    data3   data3  data3
data4     data4    data4   data4  data4

sum        sum      sum     sum    sum
```

I have those sums of those columns but I want to show the data 4 in the detail in the sum i dont want those numbers included.  Any ideas?

Comment: i'm not clear on what you're asking - what would your desired output be?

Comment: essentially like whats happened below but some of its not working because of the calculated fields.  Im wondering if I need do all the calculations in my proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your expression to = sum(iif(data = data4, 0, data))

Comment: I tried that but some of my fields are calculated in the report, then it errors out.

Comment: You could always replace the field with a calculation. Maybe you can be a bit more specific about the data itself?

Comment: =SUM(IIF(Fields!Letter.Value="Sales",0,IIF((Fields!Service_Revenue.Value) = 0, 0, (Fields!Service_Revenue.Value)/(Fields!ROs.Value)))) 

Here is one example.  it errors out after being ran with the "#error"

Comment: ok try to break it down. Try this first and see if it works for you
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Letter.Value="Sales",0,Fields!Service_Revenue.Value))

Comment: so it works on three of my columns, I did the calculations in my proc but it only works on the first three.

Comment: The columns that work are just numbers ie 3161 the columns that arent are dollar ammounts and such 176.74 and so on.

Comment: could be a datatype casting issue. Make sure you are comparing apples to apples (i.e. that data you are returning from your dataset are all numbers). The formatting into dollars can be done within the report itself

Comment: Right Im doing the actual format to a currency in the report, so my first three columsn are just whole numbers 1,2,3,4 I have some percentages and other numbers that display fine in the detail but when I add my conditional sum I get the #error

Comment: so is it this part of the conditional that fails: (Fields!Service_Revenue.Value)/(Fields!ROs.Value)?

Does it fail on its own in the expression? You are allowed calculations in the sum, i am suspecting other problems here

Comment: it seems to be to the conditional stuff not like the data type.  There numbers and they sum fine but when I add the condition to them it #errors out.

Comment: For the conditionals, you have to make sure that every part evaluates correctly. VB does not do short circuiting, so if there is a problem in one part the whole expression fails, even it that part is not used.
I cannot pinpoint where the exact problem is without more information. But at least you are in the right direction.

Comment: Im not necessarily a novice to reporting but the VB isnt my stong point,  any direction to start troubleshooting would be appreciated.